# Python IP Check

Tags: python, ip

Given the range xxx.xxx.xxx.(195-223)
Is that correct to write it in xxx.xxx.xxx.196/29 and check whether an IP is in the given network by doing

```
from ipaddr import IP, CIDR 
#if IP('xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx') in IP('xxx.xxx.xxx.196/29') or
#if IP('xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx') in CIDR('xxx.xxx.xxx.196/29')
```

Answer (score 2):

I didn't see IP in ipaddr, only IPAddress.
May be like this?

```
from ipaddr import IPAdddress, IPNetwork

if IPAddress('10.0.0.195') in IPNetwork('10.0.0.196/29'):
    pass
```

Comment: I tried to look for ipaddr doc http://packages.python.org/ipaddr/ can't seem to find usage of IPAddress/IPNetwork, or is it the wrong one what I was looking at..

Comment: I just using easy_install ipaddr and looking help(ipaddr).

Comment: That would validate IP in the range of 10.0.0.193 to 10.0.0.198?

Comment: If I would like to validate IP in the range of 10.0.0.195 to 10.0.0.200 for example, do I really have to convert it to CIDR beforehand?

Comment: Also you can use construction like IPAddress('10.0.0.194') < IPAddress(my_ip_string) < IPAddress('10.0.0.200')

Comment: ('10.0.0.194') < (my_ip_string) < ('10.0.0.200') without IPAddress seems to validate too?

Comment: I mean you using my_ip_string as variable which checking.

Comment: without IPAddress you receive AttributeError.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used the `ipaddr` module, but note that /29 means that your network mask is 255.255.255.248 and that you only have the latest 3 bits to address 2^3 = 8 different hosts in your network ranging from xxx.xxx.xxx.248 to xxx.xxx.xxx.255. That's outside of the range you want to check.

For more information, please have a look at the [subnetwork](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork) wikipedia page.